# Make a button appear from top on scrolling down without plugins only with css and vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want a button to smoothly appear (animate) from hidden to top: 10px right: 10px.

I cannot use any libraries, only css and vanilla js.

My current solution is as following:
`

```
@keyframes example {
    from { top: -10px }
    to { top: 10px }
}

.navButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2000;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

`

The button is initially there, then when I refresh, it appears from the top, but laggs heavily.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, we expect you to at least try something yourself. You can ask here if you have problems with what you have tried, but you need to do the initial work at least.

Comment: Please post the which you have tried

Comment: hi, sorry, you're right, I added a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS works fine for me. What browser are you using?

To get it more smooth you could Play with the "from position" and the duration like i did here (tested in Edge, Firefox an Chrome):

```css
@keyframes example {
    from { top: -100px }
    to { top: 10px }
}

.navButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2000;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="navButton">test button</button>
```